# Is loading a built exe from QT Creator different from loading the exe from file system? [webkit issue]

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qwebview, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm writing a desktop app that connects to my company's intranet. The page I'm trying to load is HTTP, but it will redirect to a login site that uses HTTPS. The app loads the page well when launched from QT Creator (both redirection and authentication succeeded, and the page is shown correctly), but when I run the app from file system (all DLLs are put into the folder correctly), the loading fails (QWebView's loadFinished(bool) signal is emitted with a false, which is a rare case as I learned online). I can catch the first 302 redirection status from QNetworkManager's SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), but when the second time the signal is captured, the status becomes invalid. From QNetworkReply's documentation I read that "If the connection was not HTTP-based, this attribute will not be present." I don't know why. In addition, not SSL error signal is emitted. Since the app runs well from QT Creator. I believe it should be due to some difference in environment when launching. Anyone have a clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No experience with QTCreator, but check for permission issues?

Comment: QT creator is not running with privilege. One thing is that the app runs ok from FS several days ago but fails now. (I tried the backed up build from several days ago recently but with no luck) I don't know if that's some server side problem since I tried on multiple computers, which all managed to run the app before. But the most weird thing is why it has no problem when launching from IDE.